# Find record created this week CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Tried doing this:

```
$sdate = new \DateTime('last saturday');
$edate = new \DateTime();

$query = $this->Orders->find()->where(["Orders.created BETWEEN '.$sdate.' AND '.$edate.'"]);
```

even tried using date_diff in php and mySql

```
$diff = date_diff($sdate,$edate);
$query = $this->Orders->find()->where(['(DATEDIFF(Orders.created, NOW())) >' => $diff]);
```

Both don't seem to work. Any help here will be terribly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query builder:

```
$sdate = new \DateTime('last saturday');
$edate = new \DateTime();

$query = $this->Orders->find()
    ->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($sdate, $edate) {
        return $exp->between('created', $sdate, $edate);
    });
```

More info: [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)

Comment: Didn't work when using varchar as created column, had to change it DATETIME

For anyone who stumbles on this and makes the same mistake 
I did

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->Orders->find()->where(["Orders.created > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"]);
```

Try this one.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this will get records from the last 7 days. Which is not what I want. What I want is to get all the weekly records e.g from Monday to wednesday,  if today is wednesday.

Comment: oh ok. try it below.

Orders.created >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())

Comment: First it says DATEADD does not exist, then I changed it to DATE_ADD
Now it says:
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-7, GETDATE())' at line 1

Comment: Look up the MySQL documentation for the DATE_ADD function. DATEADD is the MS-SQL version, and the parameters are different.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, and here's how I did it relatively easily, yet using CakePHP approach (as opposed to using plain SQL):

```
$query = $this->Orders->find('all', array(
    // some find parameters such as group, order etc. may go here
));
$query->where([
    'Orders.created >=' => $query->func()->date_sub([
        $query->func()->now(),
        'INTERVAL 1 WEEK' => 'literal',
    ]),
]);
```

Sources:

- [query-builder.html#using-sql-functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

Comment: Just found my own answer while searching for this again. **Bad news**: can't upvote my own post; **good news**: found an error and fixed it

Comment: Yet another *finding my own answer* check-in